# Проблема с подключением Font Awesome

Tags: html, css, sass, fontawesome

Cкачал весь архив, файл css конвертировал в sass, положил в папку libs, прописал в файл font.sass в таком виде:

```
+font-face("fontAwesome", "../fonts/fontAwesome/fontawesome-webfont", $file-formats: eot woff ttf)
```

В основном файле стилей main.sass добавил использование шрифта:

```
@import "../app/libs/fontAwesome/font-awesome.sass"
```

В файле стилей шрифта присутствует такая строка

```
@font-face
    font-family: 'FontAwesome'
    src: url('../app/fonts/fontAwesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3')
    src: url('../app/fonts/fontAwesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3') format("embedded-opentype"), url('../app/fonts/fontAwesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3') format("woff2"), url('../app/fonts/fontAwesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.3') format("woff"), url('../app/fonts/fontAwesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3') format("truetype"), url('../app/fonts/fontAwesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3#fontawesomeregular') format("svg")
    font-weight: normal
    font-style: normal
```

**Ее нужно убрать?**

Использую index.html такую конструкцию:

```
<div class="adress">
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>105066, г. Москва, Переулок Токмаков, дом 11         
</div>
```

Получается такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ожидалось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Console

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ссылка на архив проекта https://yadi.sk/d/YhSyM7e5w6ML5

Comment: дайте ссылку на тестовую страницу. и что говорит консоль?

Comment: так я на localhost работаю (

Comment: сделайте архив и напишите ссылку для скачивания

Comment: добавил скрин из консоли и ссылку на архив

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас проблема с путями к файлам шрифта.
В файле `_optimized_gulp_sass/app/css/main.min.css` измените все начала путей с `../app/fonts/fontAwesome/` на `../fonts/fontAwesome/`

*Результат:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Странно, как тогда другие шрифты отображаются, которые точно также подключены и в той же папке лежат?

Comment: @Miroslav по остальным шрифтам у Вас в `_optimized_gulp_sass/app/css/fonts.min.css` указан правильный путь начинающийся на `../fonts/`, пример `url(../fonts/Exo2Bold/Exo2Bold.eot?#iefix`

Comment: изменил в font-awesome.sass - да, там было как вы говорите, но не помогло (((

Comment: @Miroslav в том архиве который Вы дали, в файле /app/index.html Вы подключаете файлы .css В текущем подключении проблемы не наблюдается - goo.gl/ZMsFLz Покажите пожалуйста как и где Вы подключаете файлы .sass На первый взгляд видим в **font-awesome.sass** путь `../app/fonts/` и в **main.sass**  `@import "../app/libs/fontAwesome/font-awesome.sass"` Проверьте корректность путей.

Comment: я подключаю их всех в файле main.sass. http://take.ms/IeZOV , пробовал убрать app - Тогда Sublime выдает ошибку, что данный файл не найден либо не читаем. К примеру, таким образом у меня подключена owl-carousel и она прекрасно работает ((( хотя после удаления "app" в пути к файлу она тоже работает (((

Comment: действительно трабла была в путях

Answer (score 1):

Просто перенеси папку fonts из font-awesome в папку с обычными шрифтами

Comment: точнее её содержимое

Answer (score 0):

если срочно нужно решить проблему, попробуйте подключить так:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: у ТС проблема после конвертации в sass. при чем здесь обычное подключение css ?

Comment: ваш способ работает... но это ж не совсем правильное решение)))